# laravel4 where can I find the testcases?

Tags: php, testing, laravel, laravel-4

I was looking at github for the laravel4 source code. But I didn't find any tests for the framework code!
Is laravel not an open source project? How can someone commit a patch without testing it?

So my question is: Where do I find the tests for the laravel framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking at is:

> https://github.com/laravel/laravel

That is the framework bootstrap that they provide you so you can clone the project down and start using Laravel with their predefined structure and files. In there, you would not see the core Laravel code at all because Laravel comes as a `composer` package and will be loaded after running `composer` commands.

The framework code itself is in another project titled **Laravel Framework (Kernel)** which resides at

> https://github.com/laravel/framework.

In there you will see three folders, `src` and `tests` amongst them.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `composer update` you must add `--dev`

```
composer update --dev
```

This adds the packages that are requqired for development, including the test suite and Mockery.

Here is a guide to help you submit to the framework:

http://driesvints.com/blog/how-to-contribute-to-laravel-4